# Cannot drop the database encryption key because it is currently in use

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to create a backup of my sql managed instance database to blob storage. However am encountering the below error after trying to turn off encryption key as follows:

```
use master
ALTER DATABASE [db1] SET ENCRYPTION OFF;

use [db1]
DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
GO

Msg 33105, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Cannot drop the database encryption key because it is currently in use. Database encryption needs to be turned off to be able to drop the database encryption key.
```

I have read all MS documentation and everything is pointing to what I have done above.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Encryption/decryption is an asynchronous operation and can take some time to complete. Have you checked the output of `select * from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` for your `db_id` to ensure that `encryption_state` has changed from 5 (decryption in progress) to 1 (unencrypted)? You may also need to do a FULL backup to clear any encrypted data remaining in the transaction log. See: [DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-database-encryption-key-transact-sql)

Comment: Also you don't need to drop the key once the db is unencrypted

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks, you are 100% correct. Waited until it was finished then did my backup without issues

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Could you consider posting your comment as an actual answer? In my opinnion, this would be a benefit for the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you cannot drop the database encryption key because encryption is still in use. To resolve this issue, you should follow these steps:

**Check Encryption State**

Ensure that the database is not actively using encryption.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys WHERE database_id = DB_ID('YourDatabaseName');
```

If the `encryption_state` is not `2` (unencrypted), then encryption is still in use.

**Ensure No Active Connections**

Encryption keys cannot be dropped while the database is in use.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE database_id = DB_ID('YourDatabaseName');
```

If there are active connections, you may need to wait until there are no connections before proceeding.

**Drop Encryption Key:**

```
USE [YourDatabaseName];
DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY;
```

Replace `YourDatabaseName` with the actual name of your database in the queries above.